# What FPDEF and TFPDEF mean in Python grammar?

Tags: python, grammar

I read Python's grammar file (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) and I don´t understand what TFPDEF and FPDEF mean. I hope you can help me :)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to google it?

Comment: I did but didn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the way such identifiers are named in [[Python 3]: Full Grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), one can conclude (as I didn't see anything officially stated) that:

- ***tfpdef***:

  - Used to describe a typed argument (*typedargslist* element)
  - Stands for: **t**yped **f**unction **p**arameter **def**inition
- ***fpdef***:

  - Didn't see it, but it might refer to an argument or parameter (in general)

There's also a *vfpdef* (used to describe a *vararg*). I guess it's obvious where the **v** comes from.

Answer (score 0):

the [Python 3.8 version](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/grammar.html) has more comments explaining it

they're basically just `NAME`s (`T` variants have an optional typing declaration), so:

```
def foo(a, b): pass
```

would be parsed via the following subset of rules:

```
funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ':' func_body_suite

parameters: '(' [typedargslist] ')'

typedargslist: tfpdef (',' tfpdef)*

tfpdef: NAME

func_body_suite: simple_stmt

simple_stmt: small_stmt NEWLINE

small_stmt: pass_stmt
```